# Async Lucene.Net Indexing

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, lucene.net

Is it possible to use IndexWriter (Lucene.net 3.0.3) to write an index asynchronously?

I want to be able to perform writes and indexing asynchronously and await the result. Can't find any sample online. Thanks.

Comment: `I want to be able to perform writes and indexing asynchronously` They are already done asynchronously. Don't worry about it. Just use *Commit* to flush all the data to disk.

Comment: Thank you EZI. I simply wrapped the whole process in await Task.Run(() so that I can await it from the caller. Just verified with Luke.Net indexing works this way okay and I am able to call it from an async method. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I can't accept as answer, no enough points to be able to I guess.

Comment: @Machiavelli Wrapping it in a Task.Run doesn't make it async. It needs to be using async calls all the way down for you to benefit. Otherwise you are just running code synchronously with the overhead of running within a Task.

Comment: @PeterMorris yes very true.